# The difference between 规范，规则，规章，规矩，规定，规律

Tags: meaning, mandarin, difference

After seeing in class these words (规定，规律，规范，规矩，规章）, I’m in trouble to recognize the difference between them. I’m aware that some are used for country law, some for rules in society etc but I need a clarification.

Can someone help me to deconstruct the word and explain why a certain word is used for this certain purpose?

Comment: what is "country law" ?

Comment: Country’s law would be 法律 I guess

Comment: 规定 stipulation, 规律 regular, 规范 code, 规矩 rule, or parent's law for you, 规章 regulation or clauses of regulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

规 = rule/ regulate; 范 = model/ limit

规范 (n):  specification

Example: 做事要有规范 have to have specification when we do things

~

规 = rule/ regulate; 则 = standard

规则(n): rules

Example: 游戏规则 rules of the game

~

规 = rule/ regulate; 章 = regulation

规章(n):rules and regulations

Example:  法律上的规章 rules and regulations of law

~

规 = rule/ regulate; 矩 = guild

规矩(n): rule

Example: 公司的规矩 company's rule

~

规 = rule/ regulate; 定 = set

规定(n): standard/ rule

Example: 门的尺寸有规定 there's standard on the dimension of door;

规定(v) set rule

Example: 规定不准空运锂电池 set rule to forbid transport lithium battery by air

~

规 = rule/ regulate; 律= control

规律(n): orderly pattern

Example: 有规律地進行 execute in orderly pattern

Answer (score 3):

**规矩、规定，规则** are relatively close,cf."汉语同义词词典＂**［同］** 名词。指共同遵守的行为规范和准则。可与＂有、是、遵守、违反、合乎＂等动词搭配。

**［异］** 
**［规矩** 着重指某种行为标准或习惯。多是人们约定俗称或长期沿袭下来的，不成文的，还常与＂立、定、兴、懂、守＂等动词搭配。可构成＂循规蹈矩＂。多用于口语。**例**：（１）房东老太太的规矩是每到夜里十点半就关院门，一根大铁栓外加一把大铁锁，关得，牢牢实实。（陈玙＜夜幕下的哈尔滨＞）（２）我不坐。我们庄稼人有个规矩，不坐重载车。（李准＜黄河东流去＞）（３）人乡随俗。到哪儿听哪儿的，入了医院，就守医院的规矩。（谌容＜人到中年＞）（４）我家另一条规矩：无论大人孩子都得参加劳动（梁斌＜童年＞）（５）那时候，人们，尤其是青年，就都循规蹈矩，既不嚣张，也不浮动，一心向着＇正路＇前进了。（鲁迅＜一点比喻＞）

**［规定］** 着重指所制定的关于事物的数量、质量标准，或处理事物的方式方法，可以成文的，也可以口头宣布的。使用范围比＂规矩＂宽。还常与＂实行、执行、符合＂等动词搭配。通用于口语和书面语。**例**（１）领事裁判和片面最惠国待遇的规定，破坏了中国的司法权，扩大了资本主义国家的侵略权益。（初级中学课本＜中国历史＞）（２）上级有过明确的规定，在新区不能随便吸收战士，防止敌人派遣的奸细混到队伍里来。（吴强＜李小虎投军＞）（３）可某些单位为了给某些人以方便，连职干部从师里便可直接调往外军区。这当然是违反规定的（李存葆＜高山下的花环＞）（４）乘交通车进城。每人收费一元二角，这是最近开始实行的新规定。。。（黄裳＜东单日记＞）

**［规则］** 着重指制定出来的供大家共同遵守的制度、章程。一般是成文的，如＂比赛～、交通～、考试～、借书～、管理～＂等。还常与＂制定、执行＂等动词搭配。通用于口语和书面语。**例**（１）旧体诗、戏曲、大鼓书等都有规则，这些规则都与平仄有关。（老舍＜本固枝荣＞）（２）这时我才恍然大悟，回想起来，我们确实冒失，直接去找吴晗同志要书是违反秘密工作的规则的。（戴兔＜难忘的会见＞）（３）按比赛规则，在跳台上停留的时间过长，是要扣分的，所以他绝不允许队员养成这种不良习惯。（李铃修＜厄运＞）（４）汉字不是拼音，不是教会二三十个字母和一套拼写规则就能了事的。（吕叔湘＜关于语文教学的两点基本认识＞）

**［附］**＂规矩＂兼属形容词。形容人行为端正老实，或事物合乎标准或常理，如＂这个人老老实实，很规矩＂，＂说话很规矩＂。＂规定＂兼属动词。表示制定出关于事物的数量、质量标准，或处理事物的方式方法。（见［规定／限定］）＂规则＂兼属形容词。形容在形状、结构或分布上合乎一定的方式，整齐，如＂断壁上密布着一个个不规则的石孔＂。

**规律** compared to 法则：**［同］** 名词。指事物之间内在的必然联系。这种联系不断重复出现，在一定条件下经常起作用，并且决定着事物必然向着某种趋向发展。
**［异］**  **［法则]** 多用于哲学和社会科学著述，如＂自然～、经济～、价值～＂等。用于书面语。科学语体，**例**：（１）想起来，这倒很合乎辩证法的由量变到质变的法则。（刘白羽＜灯火＞）（２）当然，没有人横加干涉或强迫命令，而自然规律和法则也没有人能够违抗或背道而驰。（吴晓铃＜漫话方言＞）（３）集中兵力的法则，正是战胜堡垒主义的工具。（毛泽东＜中国革命战争的战略问题＞）（４）但是，在作人上，我有一定的宗旨与基本的法则，什么事都可将就，而不能超过自己划好的界限。（老舍＜我的母亲＞）

**［规律］** 使用频率比＂法则＂高，使用范围比＂法则＂宽，可用于学术性著述，也可用于一般事理的表达，如＂历史～、社会～、经济～、客观～、特殊～、发展～、必然～、普遍～、发现～、掌握～、符合～、违反～＂等。通用于口语和书面语，可构成＂规律性＂。**例**：（１）（李四光）从变形泥巴中找寻着构造形式的规律。（徐迟＜地质之光＞）（２）科学的任务是一方面发现事实，一方面在事实里边寻找秩序，发现规律。（吕叔湘＜语言和语言学＞）（３）普通话只有２１个声母，３８个韵母，４个声调，依声配合规律拼成４００多个音节，配以４声总共不超过１３００个音节。（申小龙＜中国文化语言学＞）（４）我国的江河，大小千百条，却有一个规律，都往东流，最终流入大海去___这叫做＂万河朝宗＂。（杨朔＜海市＞）（５）人的认识，主要地依赖于物质的生产活动，逐渐地了解自然的现象，自然的性质，自然的规律性、人和自然的关系；。。。（毛泽东＜实践论＞）

much more at **bkrs** (numbers are frequency numbers)：as nouns: **规定** II
[stipulation; prescription; formulation]∶预先制定的规则
关于奖金如何发放, 上级最近有新的规定 #423
**规律**:law; regular pattern:
客观规律 objective law
供求规律 the law of supply and demand
历史发展的规律 law of the development of history
自然规律 law of nature #2022
**规范**（约定俗成或明文规定的标准） standard; norm; specification; specs; canon; canonical; performance specification （设备的）#1647
**规矩** [rule; established practice] 规则与礼法1) rule; custom
2) social etiquette; manners
这孩子真没规矩。 This child has no manners.#3739
**规章** rules; regulations:
改革不合理的规章制度 reform irrational rules and regulations#8458

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain in English ?

Comment: see dictionaries, esp. bkrs

Comment: No problem take your time, I’m also working on understanding it